# Recommendation for saving floating point values with low precision and smallest space needed?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I have one column which I'll put floating point values into it. the column only need to save number from 0 to 100, with floating point up to double decimal digit precision behind the decimal point. so it need to be able to save from 0.00 to 100.00. what kind of data type I should assign to the MYSQL column that suitable for this kind of scenario? I see in phpmyadmin there are float, single, double, and real. I heard about all of them, but in C in Delphi. But in database, I usually just used double to make everything easier. But as this table will be always growing, I just want to save the smallest space possible. which data type I should use for this situation, which also gives the best performance, if that's possible? thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with floating point up to double decimal digit precision

There is no such thing. Floating-point doesn't have decimal digits.

What you need is [DECIMAL(5,2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).

Comment: yes, I think that's what I'm searching for. I read the description, and it looks like it can specify how much byte it needs to reserve. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use integer type column for both storing and performance.

Multiply/divide by 100 for presentation.

Numbers from 0 to 10000 will fit into 2 bytes [SMALLINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html) and it's the smallest size possible for your case.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this. but that would makes my code harder to read, and 6 months later, I will be left thinking about why I was multiplying or dividing by 100 in the first place. but thanks anyway. :)